# How can I find out whether I can be seen from outside in my iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, http, networking

Using services like http://canyouseeme.org/ one can find out whether a particular port is open and his (public) IP is reachable from outside world.

Assuming I have my (expected) public IP and port, is there some easier or more reliable way to check my reachability than e.g. calling canyouseeme.org ?

Comment: You could issue a Ping and see if there is a response, this technique is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553168/ping-to-a-server-port-from-iphone

Comment: The question you've linked to shows how to ping a specific port on a server from an iPhone. I believe this question is asking how to ping a port on an iPhone from somewhere else.

Comment: exactly, I need the other direction

Answer (score 0):

iPhone's don't have a public IP (*as far as I know*).

Using 3G coverage you get allocated a local IP on your networks WAN.

Using WiFi you get allocated a local IP from your router.

Therefore I doubt you'll ever be able to truly identify your iPhone using an IP you think is associated with it (*but probably isn't*)

Comment: Actually, that's fine for me, I use the Bonjour API to try mapping the port over UPnP or NAT-PMP on the router if possible. It might work but in some cases it won't and that's why I need to be sure the IP returned from the API is really reachable.